# How to switch between the OnTriggerExit/Enter logic depending on the situation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is attached to two gameobjects.

One it's colliding area the collider is big enough so when the game start the player is already inside the collider area and then when he exit the area everything is working fine.

The problem is when I attached the object to another gameobject with collider but this time the collider s smaller and he is inside the bigger collider so now the player is entering the smaller collider and not first time exiting. but I want in both case to make the same effect.

If the player exit the collider he slow down wait then turn around and move inside back.
The same I want to make when the player getting closer to the fire flames slow down wait turn around and move back in it's just with the flames the player entering the collider area and then exit while in the bigger collider he first exit then enter.

Screenshot of the two colliders areas. The small one on the left is the one the player entering first and not exiting.  The game start when the player is in the bigger collider area.

[image: Colliders areas]

And the script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class DistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform targetToRotateTowards;
    public Transform colliderArea;
    public float lerpDuration;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    [TextArea(1, 2)]
    public string textToShow;
    public GameObject descriptionTextImage;
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;
    public ThirdPersonUserControl thirdPersonUserControl;

    private Animator anim;
    private float timeElapsed = 0;
    private float startValue = 1;
    private float endValue = 0;
    private float valueToLerp = 0;
    private bool startRotating = false;
    private bool slowOnBack = true;
    private bool exited = false;
    private Vector3 exitPosition;
    private float distance;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = transform.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (startRotating)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation,
    Quaternion.LookRotation(targetToRotateTowards.position - transform.position),
    rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (exitPosition != new Vector3(0, 0, 0) && slowOnBack)
        {
            distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, exitPosition);
        }

        if (distance > 5 && slowOnBack)
        {
            slowOnBack = false;
            StartCoroutine(SlowDown());
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == colliderArea.name)
        {
            exited = true;
            slowOnBack = true;
            exitPosition = transform.position;
            thirdPersonUserControl.enabled = false;
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(true);
            text.text = textToShow;
            StartCoroutine(SlowDown());
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == colliderArea.name)
        {
            exited = false;
            startRotating = false;
            text.text = "";
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SlowDown()
    {
        timeElapsed = 0;

        while (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
        {
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;

            yield return null;
        }

        if (exited)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

            startRotating = true;
            StartCoroutine(SpeedUp());
        }

        if (slowOnBack == false)
        {
            thirdPersonUserControl.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SpeedUp()
    {
        timeElapsed = 0;

        while (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
        {
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(endValue, startValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Two problems I'm facing right now :

- The smaller collider the player enter it then exit and the bigger collider the player exit it then enter so I need to change somehow the `OnTriggerExit/Enter` behavior logic in the script. but how to make the logic ?
- Maybe it's better to make the script to be on the player object only and make it some how generic so I can drag to it many colliders and to make the effect in each one of the colliders the problem is how to make a text field for each collider area ? Now because I attach the script to each collider object I have one `colliderArea` variable but if I want to make the script only attached to the player I need to change the `colliderArea` variable to a `List<Transform> collidersAreas` and then how to create a text field/area to each collider area in the List ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do this by creating two tags, `NoExit` and `NoEntry`. Once the tags are created you can set the tag on the GameObjects that hold your colliders. Then you can check for tags in the `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` and act accordingly.

I can't tell for sure which functionality you've got written is for which case, or if it's both - everything looks muddled. Ultimately what you should be going for is a function like `RepositionPlayer`, that moves them back to before they're violating the no entry or no exit rules, and then some kind of `OnPlayerRepositioned` event that restores their control.

I'll leave it up to you to split out your functionality, but in general I'd look to do something like the following:

```
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "NoExit")
    {
        RepositionPlayer();
    }
    else if(other.tag == "NoEntry")
    {
        OnPlayerRepositioned();
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "NoExit")
    {
        OnPlayerRepositioned();
    }
    else if(other.tag == "NoEntry")
    {
        RepositionPlayer();
    }
}
```

And again here it's not clear to me what you're trying to do to reposition the player, but it looks like it's something like:

```
private void RepositionPlayer()
{
    // Stuff that needs to happen to reposition the player
    exited = true;
    slowOnBack = true;
    exitPosition = transform.position;
    thirdPersonUserControl.enabled = false;
    descriptionTextImage.SetActive(true);
    text.text = textToShow;
    StartCoroutine(SlowDown());
}

private void OnPlayerRepositioned()
{
    // stuff you need to do to clear the "repositioning" status
    exited = false;
    startRotating = false;
    text.text = "";
    descriptionTextImage.SetActive(false);
}
```

Splitting up the logic like this makes it easier to both read and maintain.

Comment: I will explain what i'm trying to archive.  In general to block the player from moving any move further. The idea is in some places in the game i want to make the player to be blocked from moving. my idea is this logic : The player is entering/exiting specific area he start slow down smooth to stop. after stopping wait x seconds then start rotating facing back and while rotating also start moving with increasing the moving speed when exiting/entering back slow down again.  and i enable/disable the thirdPersonUserControl so all this will be automatic.

Comment: I control the player until exit/enter depending the situation and then all the slow/wait/rotate/speed up part will be automatic then in the end i enable the thirdPersonUserControl again.

Comment: I will try your solution and also will add a small very short video clip i recorded showing what happens now when the player exit the big collider area it will show my logic.

Comment: @SharoSA yeah I think I understand that, and your problem is that sometimes you want that behavior to trigger when the player **exits** an area (like the level extents) and sometimes you want that behavior to trigger when the player **enters** an area (like a fire), right? This is at least my understanding, and is what I cover in the answer here.

Comment: With the code I've provided, *whatever is triggering the behavior*, if your player is supposed to be repositioned then the actual act of repositioning is handled by `RepositionPlayer()`. Once they've been moved, the act of restoring the player is handled by `OnPlayerRepositioned()`. This lets you split up the logic - you can decide **when** you reposition the player independently of **how** you reposition the player. I propose deciding **when** to reposition based on GameObject tags that you should add to the collider GameObjects.

Comment: You would add a tag like `NoExit` to a collider the player should not exit, like the level extents collider. You would add a tag like `NoEntry` to a collider the player should not enter, like a region on fire. Then you can sort out whether entering a trigger means you should *start* repositioning or if you're *done* repositioning based on whether your character should or should not be entering the trigger. Same is true for exiting the trigger.

Comment: There is a problem.  when i move the player to the collider tagged NoEntry in the event OnTriggerEnter it's detecting the player and the player is untagged.  The other.tag name is untagged and i added the tag NoEntry to the collider.  but when the player is inside the NoExit or exit the NoExit it's working fine with the collider tagged NoExit.  why it's detecting the player as other in the NoEntry collider ?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the script is also attached to the player ? The script is attached to two objects. the small collider object and to the player.  maybe i should attach the script to each coolider and not to the player at all ?

Comment: @SharoSA where is the script attached? It sounds like you're adding the `NoEntry` logic to a script attached to the `NoEntry` collider, as opposed to attached to the player. If it were attached to the player then `this.collider` would be the player's collider and `collider other` would be the region, which is attached to the `NoEntry` object.

Comment: @SharoSA if you're trying to move the player from two different scripts (one attached to the player and one attached to the collider zone) then you're going to have a bad time. Who should be owning that action? This is the question you should always be asking yourself - *who is responsible for this interaction?* Should a zone need to know about a player, how to move them, etc.? I think all that logic best resides with the player. The zone should just know if it's `NoEntry`, `NoExit`, or something else, and then it's up to interacting objects to decide what to do about entries and exits.

Comment: My mistake sorry. i removed the script from the collider.  the script is attached now only to the player and it's working perfect.  sorry for the mess.

Comment: @SharoSA hey no worries at all! Really happy for you that it's working! That rush when it just suddenly works is why I think we all do this haha. Junkies for success <3 Happy for you :)

Comment: The next thing i need to do some how is to extend a bit the script.  for example the TextArea attribute and the variable textToShow now it's showing the same text for each tag if NoEntry or NoExit same text will show.  i want some how to add to the inspector that each collider will have his own text to show. each collider will have his own textToShow variable.  the logic is two options NoEntry NoExit but what if i tag more colliders and i want that it will display another text on each one ? I will think about it. maybe i need editor script for that ?

Comment: @SharoSA that's a different kind of question and a bit more involved than we can talk about in comments here. Would you like to start a new question?

Comment: you right.  i opened a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533919/how-to-make-textarea-attribute-field-to-be-created-for-each-collider-when-the-ev